# C++ invalid conversion from base to derived

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class `Board` which contains a pointer array of pointers, called `Space** bo`, each of the pointer points to an instance of the `Space` class. I have a derived class called `SnakesAndLaddersSpace` which inherits from `Space`, and `SnakesAndLaddersBoard` which inherits from `Board`.

Essentially , in my `SnakesAndLaddersBoard` class I want to change the `Space** bo`, which it inherits, to `SnakesAndLaddersSpace** bo`, how would I go about this?

This is what I'm doing in the `SnakesAndLaddersBoard` Class

```
SnakesAndLaddersBoard::Board::Board(int w, int h)
{ 
    width=w;
    height=h;//set up the size of the board

    bo = new SnakesAndLaddersSpace*[height];  // <<-- error
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        bo[i] = new SnakesAndLaddersSpace[width]; 
    }
}
```

And here's the error I'm getting

> SnakesAndLaddersBoard.cpp|13|error: invalid conversion from ‘SnakesAndLaddersSpace**’ to           ‘Space**’ [-fpermissive]|

Comment: **Where** do you get that error? Which line is number 13? And instead of describing your code in text, please the code instead, especially the declarations and definitions of the classes/variables involved.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, come on, it is only one point in the snippet, where this conversion occurs with only 2 candidates.

Comment: @Lol4t0 We can't really tell if that's the line in question, so better safe than sorry.

Comment: I dropped it in a pastebin here if that helps, there's a good amount of code, http://pastebin.com/pMW7RHkk thanks

Comment: this line is the line in question "bo = new SnakesAndLaddersSpace*[height];"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because `SnakesAndLaddersSpace**` is not compatible with `Space**`, they are just unrelated due to too high level of indirection.
Of cause, you still can assign pointer to `SnakesAndLaddersSpace` to the pointer to `Space` type, but you cannot assign pointer to pointer to `SnakesAndLaddersSpace` to the pointer to pointer to `Space`.

```
bo = new Space*[height]; // look here!!!
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    bo[i] = new SnakesAndLaddersSpace[width];
}
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to have solved the problem, the only other issue I'm having now though, is I don't seem to be able to call the methods in SnakesAndLaddersSpace as below 

http://pastebin.com/QQtfUp5W

Comment: @user2327041, Well you cannot call functions declared in derived class from the base class. In common case, you can declare pure virtual function in the base class and implement it in derived, but it does not look reasonable here. Otherwise, you can use `static_cast` to cast from base class to derived, if you are sure, that pointer to base class contains a pointer to derived. Or, may be you should rethink your architecture for clear solution.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't make sense... If you are making a new variable then shouldn't you be calling the constructor?
bo[i]= new SnakesAndLaddersSpace(width);
..?

Comment: Nope, in this case the OP is allocating `width` objects of type `SnakesAndLaddersSpace` and returning a pointer to the first one as a result. In your answer the code will only allocate one element using a constructor that receives an integer argument. A very different thing as you can see.